# How can I make lightttp and nginx run on the same Port with different IP addresses (same interface)?

Tags: nginx, port, lighttpd

I am running a PiHole on my RPi, and at the same time a `Nginx` Proxy server. I must have both of them listening to port 80, in this case, pihole must have `lighttpd` listening to port 80.
To solve this problem I created two ips adresses, in the same interface (192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3), and I want to give both of them to lighttpd and Nginx. I was able to change lighttpd configuration (to listen only on 192.168.0.3), and I think that everything is ok. Then I have my nginx server failing, I guess because of the wildcard that makes nginx listen port 80 in every IP Address.

Nginx Current Status

```
Jun 25 00:30:30 sousahost nginx[3040]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Jun 25 00:30:30 sousahost nginx[3040]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 25 00:30:31 sousahost nginx[3040]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 25 00:30:31 sousahost nginx[3040]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 25 00:30:32 sousahost nginx[3040]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jun 25 00:30:32 sousahost nginx[3040]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

How can I solve my case in this situation? I guess the obvious solution is to tell Nginx to listen only on a certain IP Adress, but I can't figure it out (is that possible to make?). How can I make sure that Nginx is only listing to a certain IP?

Most of my configurations are like this one:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.1.3:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name ads.sousa.host;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/pi.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/pi.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/pi.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://192.168.1.3:80;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://192.168.1.3:80 https://ads.sousa.host/admin;
    }
  }
```

Plus, am I thinking well? Is creating two ips on the same interface a valid, and good solution? I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: I am surprised how i got -1 score, 2 seconds after posting. Someone clearly have a good sense of judging.

Comment: Have you considered using Apache with different contexts for both?

Comment: @11thdimension Why Apache? My nginx server really do its job, and use lighttpd is almost mandatory. Are you suggesting switch nginx to apache?

Comment: No, I haven't used Nginx. In Apache I use contexts for different applications which have to be served by the same `IP:Port`. For example if I have two applications Service @`localhost:8080` and Web @ `localhost:9090` then I use Apache context to map them to `localhost:80/Service` and `localhost:80/Web`. Mapping is done as reverse proxy configuration. If you're OK with having context URLs `/Service` and `/Web` then you should be able to do the same in Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the `bind` option on the `listen` directive, which should prevent `nginx` from attempting to grab the wildcard address. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) for more.

```
listen 192.168.0.2:80 bind;
```

This is effective with multiple interfaces. But not sure if it is effective with multiple addresses on one interface.

Comment: Yes, that should work fine.  If lighttpd is listening port 80 on one IP, and nginx is listening on port 80 on a different IP, then they will happily coexist.